# Result set is displaying twice in the Browser

Tags: node.js

I'm learning Node js and I'd like to understand why the output or result set is showing twice in the browser (tried with different browsers) and how to fix the issue to show the result set only once.

Here is my sample code :

```
// JavaScript source code
var express = require('express'); // Web Framework
var app = express();
var sql = require('mssql'); // MS Sql Server client

// Connection string parameters.

const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool({
  user: 'myuser',
  password: 'password123',
  server: 'localhost',
  database: 'Sample'
})

var conn = pool;

// Start server and listen on http://localhost:8080/

var server = app.listen(8080, function () {
  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log("app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
});

app.get('/groups', function (req, res) {
conn.connect().then (function() {
    var request = new sql.Request(conn);
      request.query('SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [Sample].[Table1]',function(err,        recordset) {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        res.end(JSON.stringify(recordset)); // Result in JSON format
        conn.close();
        });
    });
})
```

please advice.

Thanks.

Comment: In the Browser, output same Top10 records are showing  twice in JSON format as 2 record sets.

Comment: what does `console.log(recordset)` print ?